# Fetching Instagram Post Based on Hashtags Through Instagram Graph Api

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

So, Today I was Trying To Fetch Instagram Post Using

**Ig Hashtags Search Apis**

But I AM Unable To Fetch POST Event If I have Converted my Instagram Account to Business Account ,
But Still It Is Showing Like Below

**"message": "(#3) This edge is only available to business user or system user"**

Does Any One Know What TO do

I Have Tried This Below Api

**https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/me?fields=id,name,assigned_ad_accounts&access_token**

And Provided Access Token Also

But The Responce With Message was like

**"message": "(#3) This edge is only available to business user or system user"**

The Account is Already Of Type Business Then also It is Showing Like this